# General code for a summation in R

Tags: r, sum

I'm writing some code in R and I came across following problem: 
Basically, I want to calculate a variable `X[k]`, where `X` takes on values for each `k`, like this:

[image]

where `A` is a known variable which takes on different values for each index.

For the moment, I have something like this:

```
k <- NULL
X <- NULL
z<- 1: n
for (k in seq(along =z)){
for (j in seq (along = 1:k)){
  X[k] = 1/k*sum(A[n-k]/A[n-j+1])
 }
 }
```

which can't be right. Any idea on how to fix this one?

As always, any help would be dearly appreciated.

Comment: You need to define your `A` vector.

Comment: @Gregor: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that if I try to run your code, I will get "Error: object 'A' not found". It would be a much better example if you define an appropriate `A` object in your question.

Comment: Also, `seq()` doesn't have an argument named `along`. You can do `seq_along(z)`, or, since `z` is already a sequence, `for (k in z)` as in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
# define A
A <- c(1,2,3,4)
n <- length(A)
z <- 1:n
#predefine X (don't worry, all values will be overwritten, but it will have the same length as A
X <- A  
for(k in z){
  for(j in 1:k){
    X[k] = 1/k*sum(A[n-k]/A[n-j+1])
  }
}
```

You don't need to define z, it is only used inside the for. In this case, do `for(k in 1:n){`

Answer (score 1):

As

[image]

You can do the following

```
set.seed(42)
A <- rnorm(10)
k <- sample(length(A), 4)

calc_x <- function(A, k){
  n <- length(A)
  c_sum <- cumsum(1/rev(A)[1:max(k)])
  A[n-k]/k * c_sum[k]
}

calc_x(A,k)
```

what returns:

```
[1]  0.07775603  2.35789999 -0.45393983  0.13323284
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but the `sum of 1/A[j]` is not `1/ sum A[j]`. 1/3 + 1/4 is not 1 / (3+4)

Comment: You are absolutely right... Brain Fail on my side. Bute the code was right... Only the explainaition was FAIL!

Comment: I did not checked your code, but it gave me the impression that it was implemented right. We all slip.